# Handwriting Recognition Java

Tags: java, handwriting

I know there are other posts about this, but I cannot seem to find one strictly for handwriting. I am going to have a form and all I need to read in is 8 squares in the left hand corner that will have 3 letters proceeded by 5 numbers.

The problem with most posts is that people either post about software for writing on the screen or software that doesn't recognize handwriting yet. I would prefer to have something in java, but something simple in another language would work.

What would really work is if people could scan their documents and just type the job number for the document name, but apparently they cant do that right...

Comment: I guess, you must give up thinking in terms of words and numbers and start thinking everything to be images(pixels)

Comment: You need to do a little research on Java in relevant to OCR (Optical Character Recognition)

Comment: Did you completed the project? i mean I'm doing the same kind of project, can you please list out what you used for your purpose of recognition of handwritten letters in boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i got you correctly, you are doing offline hwr,

when i was doing offline hwr, i found most difficult separating characters in word, seems like you have them in squares, so all what you need to do is find your boxes (ie by using histogram)

and compare content of your box with each element in yours characters database (i used levenshtein distance for that)

I know it maybe not very helpful, but maybe push you on right track.

Answer (score 4):

Can you change the form? This problem will simplify a *lot* if you can change the form to be something that is easier for a machine to read. To recognize an arbitrary handwriting is *hard* as well as error prone.

What I have in mind is a form like this:

[form example http://shareworldonline.com/w3/testprep/images/test%20form.jpg](http://shareworldonline.com/w3/testprep/images/test%20form.jpg)

---

However, if you have to have handwriting, check out the solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768664/recommendations-for-handwriting-recognition-libraries-packages-in-java).